# Thunderbird (52.4.0) : Calendar not using system's timezone

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird, time-zone

I am frequently travelling between timezones. Have recently started using TB and its calendar. Today I missed an appointment because the time of that appointment was shown in home timezone while I was in a different timezone. I know that Extras > Settings > Calendar > General has a dropdown to select a different timezone - but I just do not think that I can be bothered enough to really change that whenever I travel. 
A first Google-sessions seems to confirm that there is indeed no option to make it use the systems timezone.
But... I am using scripts to change the timezone - so if this setting was stored in the registry or an .ini.file, I guess I could find a way to update it with my "travel-scripts". Any suggestions?  Or is there a better way to do this - can TB perhaps be tweaked to do what I want???

**P.S:** not interested in reminders, but rather an accurate display of appointments and their times.

Comment: You don't mention what operating system you are using.  I would imagine Thunderbird notification system would be based on the operating system's clock (there is typically not another source of time other then the time provided by the OS API) which means you either didn't have the system clock set correctly or something else is going on.  *Sounds like a user configuration error to me.*  Easy enough to confirm.  Set a appointment for one hour from now, and change your time zone to one that has a -1 offset from your current time zone.  You should get a notification in two hours instead of one.

Comment: I'm not using notifications. My system's timezone was set to "GMT" whereas Thunderbird (because I was not aware of this problem) was still using my german timezone. Today I missed an appointment which was schedule for 4pm GMT - but was shown for 17:00 (GMT+1 as in DE). So TB acted correctly - according to the config. But as I said, when my system is changed to GMT, I also want the calender to adjust.

Comment: I just tested Thunderbird 52.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 with Lightning 5.4 and Provider for Google Calendar 3.3 to synchronise with Google Calendar. I changed my system time zone to `Europe/Berlin`, which immediately changed the system time, then I restarted Thunderbird. TB's time zone did not change, but I got the reminder at the correct time before a test event.

Comment: I recently had this problem as a result of a new Windows 10 install. Unlike prior versions, Windows 10 does not ask the user for their time zone during installation, and instead defaults every install to pacific time (when not connected to the internet). I very promptly corrected the timezone after install, but not before thunderbird picked it up. It's very aggravating that the calendar not only does not use the system time, but does not even use the same time zone as the rest of Thunderbird. All of my emails have correct timestamps, but every calendar entry is off by an hour.

Answer (score -2):

See if this is what you are looking for and if it affects TB:

To let Windows 10 select and set the Time Zone automatically, click on the Start Button to open the Start Menu.

Here open Settings > Time & Language.

Now in the left pane, select Date & Time. The date & Time settings here are quite simple here as the main overview has it all. You can set the time to adjust automatically or change it manually.

In the right pane you will see a new setting Set time zone automatically.

Toggle slider button to the On position.

That’s it!

Windows 10 will now set the time of your system, depending on the physical location of your device.

Comment: Thanks. I shall check upon return to my home-timezone if Windows really gets it right. But even if it did: I said before that TB's config does not allow the flexibility to pick up the system's timezone- So how should the automatic update of the tz help?